# I want to create a function which can return the responseJson and use it to create some objects in init

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var uiNameSearch: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var uiGivenName: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func searchForName(sender: UIButton) {
    let header = ["Accept" : "application/json"]
   let name = uiNameSearch.text!
    let given = uiGivenName.text!
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Patient?family=\(name)&given=\(given)", headers: header).responseJSON { response in
        let patient = response.result.value!
        if let entry = patient.objectForKey("entry") {
            if let link = entry[0].objectForKey("link") {
                if let url = link[0].objectForKey("url") {
                    let fullNameArr = url.componentsSeparatedByString("/")

                        print(fullNameArr[fullNameArr.count-1])

                }
                //print(link)
            }
        }






}
}
}
```

**My Patient class is:**

```
class Patient {
    var name: String
    var given: String
    var id: String

init(name: String, given: String, id: String) {

}

}
```

I want to use the response in init to create objects, how can I do this?

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: I want to create a function like this: alamofireResponse()->Response<responseJson>{} to return the response like an object and tu use it in the init

Comment: Why `responseJson` in angle brackets? Do you want to use generics?

Comment: I want a function to return the response. How can  I do this?

Comment: I'ts not very clear what kind of function do you need. And how do you want to be called. Please add these details to the question, otherwise it will be difficult for people to understand what you need.